# sharepointdesinger2013 tag is misspelled

Tags: discussion

How do we go about fixing a misspelled tag?
The "n" and "g" are flipped around
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tags/sharepointdesinger2013/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there are not that many questions tagged with it, I would retag them with the correct tag.

When there are no more questions using a tag it will self destruct in a day or two

Comment: as I went to follow your suggestion, turns out there is no SPD2013 tag. By following the previous [discussions regarding versioning](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153/numeric-version-tags-considered-ok?rq=1) should they all just be moved to the SPD tag? (or is this another discussion?)

Comment: @Choggo they should be be moved to the SPD-tag without version. In a way that's another discussion, but it suites the perpose of your question: to remove faulty tags :-)

Comment: ;) will do it at home, if no one gets to it first. SE is extremely glitchy here today =\

Answer (score 2):

It will be deleted automatically at 3:00 am UTC so long as there are no posts tagged with it.

[How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags)

Comment: Thanks. At the time it was still being used, I cleaned it out this morning...